# Newly added methods are not being generated in WSDL in WCF Service

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, wsdl

I have a WCF Service which exposes couple methods and for every method an entry was being generated in .wsdl file .

It was working fine but recently, someone added new methods in different branch and It was still working fine( an entry for respective methods were being generated) But When I merged the same code to different branch, then No .wsdl description is being generated for those newly added methods Or Even though If I add new methods in the service contract.

Any hint or clue would be appreciated.

Comment: Are the new methods marked with `[OperationContract]`?  And are they `public`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I have found that in one branch the output path of .csproj file was changed to output instead of Bin. After changing the path back to bin from output directory it worked.